# Questions about the series integral test.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

According to the textbook I'm reading, the integral test on a series applies if the function f is decreasing, continuous, and positive. However, I was under the impression that a series is the sum of the terms of a sequence. How is it possible that the series is decreasing? The terms of the sequence must be positive here, so I was under the impression the series would be increasing? What am I missing?

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: I am using the Cengage Calculus Ninth Edition, chapter 9.3.

Comment: The summands of the series are decreasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function do the role in the integral of the sequence in the summation. So the series is not decreasing, but the sequence yes, for example $\frac{1}{n^2}$.